# find duplicate number in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I am debugging below problem and post the solution I am debugging and working on, the solution or similar is posted on a couple of forums, but I think the solution has a bug when num[0] = 0 or in general num[x] = x? Am I correct? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Given an array nums containing n + 1 integers where each integer is between 1 and n (inclusive), prove that at least one duplicate number must exist. Assume that there is only one duplicate number, find the duplicate one.

Note:
You must not modify the array (assume the array is read only).
You must use only constant, O(1) extra space.
Your runtime complexity should be less than O(n2).
There is only one duplicate number in the array, but it could be repeated more than once.

```
int findDuplicate3(vector<int>& nums)
{
    if (nums.size() > 1)
    {
        int slow = nums[0];
        int fast = nums[nums[0]];
        while (slow != fast)
        {
            slow = nums[slow];
            fast = nums[nums[fast]];
        }

        fast = 0;
        while (fast != slow)
        {
            fast = nums[fast];
            slow = nums[slow];
        }
        return slow;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: now I understood what you meant to say.I think for this problem where nums[i]==i then you must start from any other point.You can have one outer loop where it check where nums[i]!=i and then you can proceed from that position.Do you think this may also break?

Comment: @Khatri, num[i] == i is a circle, but not the one you are looking for when i is not the duplicate number. How do you handle this situation?

Comment: if i!=0 then it will not cause a problem because slow pointer will stuck at that position and fast will eventually reach the same position and while loop will break and in second while loop when slow is still stuck fast will reach there and find the duplicate.But when nums[0] = 0 then you need to handle that case separately.ex:int nums[] = {4,1,3,2,2} here arr[1]==1 but this will not cause a problem,you can easily figure it out using pen and paper.

Comment: This allgorithm basically doesn't work, and `x[i]=i` is the lesser of its problem. The bigger problem is that it will never see the duplicate in `[1,2,3,0,4,4]`.

Comment: There are two possibilities when arr[i] == i that are either arr[i] is a duplicate then there is no problem, above algorithm will work fine.And 2nd possibility is that arr[i] == i and arr[i] is not a duplicate (say i is non zero,we can handle that case separately ), then my claim is that you will never reach at position i by above algorithm.If you feel anything wrong in that then please provide and counter example.(Once again i==0 case is handled separately) as I don't know how to say it formally.

Comment: @n.m. please let me know if you found anything wrong in the above explanation.

Comment: @Khatri I can't see an ezplanation that would explain how any variable would be assigned the value of 4 in the above case.

Comment: @n.m. Initially slow = 4, fast = 2, in next iteration slow = 2 ,fast = 2 then first while loop breaks then you set fast = arr[0] that is 4 and move both pointer by one step, that is slow = 3 ,fast = 4 ,next iteration slow = 2 , fast =2 , and you got the repeated element.

Comment: @Khatri, for your comments, "if i!=0 then it will not cause a problem because slow pointer will stuck at that position and fast will eventually reach the same position", I am not sure if fast will eventually reach i = 0 position, since faster may be stuck in another loop, saying num[3] = 4 and num[4] = 3, but neither 3 or 4 are duplicate elements. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa I am quite getting your point, can you provide one such example.

Comment: @Khatri  "Initially slow = 4" I mean my example, not yours.

Comment: @n.m. but question says elements of the array are in the range 1 to n, but you are including 0.Assumption of this  algorithm is same, if that is not fulfilled then no doubt you can't apply this algorithm directly atleast.

Comment: @Khatri There seems to be an internal contradiction in the question, it says `x[0]==0` is a problem, so I take 0 is permitted. If it's not then the algorithm is probably OK.

Comment: @Khatri, how do you handle cases like A[2] = 3, A[3] = 4 and A[4] =2, they are circle but no duplicate.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such kind?

Comment: @Khatri, what kinds of example? I showed an example above  A[2] = 3, A[3] = 4 and A[4] =2, which makes faster and small into circle, which blocks them to find the real duplicate elements. Please feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No I mean complete array.What are the values at 0th and 1st index?

Comment: @Khatri, how it works for [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5]? In more general case, both pointers are stuck in a circle without reaching the remaining part of the array. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start with two pointers to the first element: *fast* and *slow*.
2. Define a 'move' as incrementing *fast* by 2 step(positions) and *slow* by 1.
3. After each *move*, check if *slow* & *fast* point to the same node.
4. If there is a loop, at some point they will. This is because after they are both in the loop, *fast* is moving twice as quickly as *slow* and will eventually 'run into' it.
5. Say they meet after *k moves*. This is NOT NECESSARILY the repeated element, since it might not be the first element of the loop reached from outside the loop.
   Call this element *X*.
6. Notice that *fast* has stepped *2k* times, and *slow* has stepped *k* times.
7. Move *fast* back to zero.
8. Repeatedly advance *fast* and *slow* by ONE STEP EACH, comparing after each step.
9. Notice that after another *k* steps, slow will have moved a total of *2k* steps and *fast* a total of *k* steps from the start, so they will again both be pointing to *X*.
10. Notice that if the prior step is on the loop for both of them, they were both pointing to *X-1*. If the prior step was only on the loop for *slow*, then they were pointing to different elements.
11. Ditto for *X-2, X-3,* ...
12. So in going forward, the first time they are pointing to the same element is the first element of the cycle reached from outside the cycle, which is the repeated element you're looking for.

Comment: And let me add that this is just an explanation of @Khatri's algorithm, which is good, and that you should accept his answer and not mine.

Comment: Thanks Dave,  I read your comments again above and did some exercise, I think my understanding, "when there is a circle, there must be two elements in the array pointing to the entry point of circle, and faster/slower runner met at entry point of circle (in your algorithm), and it is why the index of array of begin circle is the duplicate elements, correct? ", is exactly what you mean? If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: The faster/slower meet for the first time **SOMEWHERE** in the cycle, but not necessarily at the first (thus repeated) element. That's why you need the second step, where you move fast back to the start and advance it and slow both slowly (1 at a time). At this point we know that as soon as fast enters the loop, it will be pointing at the same element as slow, so we can use this to identify the first element, which we know must be the repeated element.

Comment: Hi Dave, I re-read my comments, and I know why we confuse each other, have some corrections, "when there is a circle, there must be two elements in the array pointing to the entry point of circle, and faster/slower runner met at entry point of circle **for the 2nd time after we reset faster running (in your algorithm)**", is that correct understanding now? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dave, another pitfall of your algorithm is, when fast and slow met for the first time, fast could already run k + n (k + 2n, k + 3n, etc.) steps, n is length of circle, and k is steps from the start point (where duplicate element asides) of the circle, slow elements run x steps (x is the distance from begin to start point of the circle), x == k only n = 0, but suppose circle is small, faster runner could already run more than one circle and met with slow runner for the first time. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Hi Dave, read again your comments, "slow will have moved a total of 2k steps and fast a total of k steps from the start, so they will again both be pointing to X", I think it is wrong since this time, slow/fast does not start from the same point (the very start). Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa If k is the move where fast and slow meet for the first time, then after k moves fast has move 2k steps, and slow has moved k steps. Now we move fast back to zero and start moving it 1 step per move instead of 2. Starting from 0, in k 1-step moves it is in position k. Slow started out in position k, so in another k 1-step moves it is in position 2k. We already know that position 2k is the same as position k.

Comment: Thanks Dave, smart and smart answer! Wondering what do you mean step 10, "10. Notice that if the prior step is on the loop for both of them, they were both pointing to X-1. If the prior step was only on the loop for slow, then they were pointing to different elements.", how previous step is in the discussion here? Wondering why you talk both X and k in above 12 process, I think using k only is enough from your above reply?

Comment: BTW, David, I am especially lost on what do you mean "prior step is on the loop for both of them, they were both pointing to X-1", what do you mean prior step, you mean X-1 (one step before meet point X) or another point? Thanks. :)

Comment: @LinMa Let's say that we start with fast moving twice per second, and slow moving once per second, and that they meet after k seconds on some spot in the loop whiche I'll call x. Then we reset fast to zero and change it's speed to move once per second. So now fast and slow are moving at the same speed. In another k seconds, they'll both be back at x. The thing to notice here is that if we unwind the clock by one second, then they'll both move backwards at the same speed, so as long as fast is still in the loop, it will equal slow.

Comment: Hi Dave, for your comments, "Then we reset fast to zero and change it's speed to move once per second. So now fast and slow are moving at the same speed. In another k seconds, they'll both be back at x", I do not quite catch this point, since for the first time, fast moves 2k steps and slow moves k steps, both are at beginning, and they meet at x -- but for the 2nd time, fast moves k steps and slow move k steps, but they move from different point (fast from beginning and slow from x), if they meet at x, it means loop size is k. I am confused. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Dave, I list the two runs (speed and begin point) just to show they are not comparable, so not sure why met with x again. It seems you derive the conclusion 2nd run will also meet at x because of similar from first run, but I think it is not. :)

Answer (score 7):

Below is my code which uses **Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int findDup(vector<int>&arr){
    int len = arr.size();
    if(len>1){
        int slow = arr[0];
        int fast = arr[arr[0]];
        while(slow!=fast){
            slow = arr[slow];
            fast = arr[arr[fast]];
        }
        fast = 0;
        while(slow!=fast){
            slow = arr[slow];
            fast = arr[fast];
        }
        return slow;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int>v = {1,2,2,3,4};
    cout<<findDup(v)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Comment** This works because zeroes aren't allowed, so the first element of the array isn't part of a cycle, and so the first element of the first cycle we find is referred to both outside and inside the cycle. If zeroes were allowed, this would fail if arr[0] were on a cycle. E.g., [0,1,1].

Comment: your while will return false on the first iteration

Comment: @Khatri, how do you handle arr[0] = 0? Suppose duplicate number is not 0.

Comment: I don't understand why that is a problem?

Comment: Here is one very nice explanation of above algorithm.[link](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=find-duplicate)
This algorithm is called Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm and uses concept of rho shape, you can read in the link for more details.

Comment: @Khatri,  how do you handle arr[0] = 0? Suppose duplicate number is not 0?

Comment: Your `fast = arr[0]` (line 9) should be `fast = arr[arr[0]]`.

Comment: This works because zeroes aren't allowed, so the first element of the array isn't part of a cycle, and so the first element of the first cycle we find is referred to both outside and inside the cycle. If zeroes were allowed, this would fail if arr[0] were on a cycle. E.g., [0,1,1].

Comment: @DaveGalvin, how do you handle cases like A[2] = 3, A[3] = 4 and A[4] =2, they are circle but no duplicate.

Comment: @LinMa Not a problem. That's an incomplete example, but any complete example you give would work. Think of it like this. We start at 0, then keep moving from where we are (call it x) to arr[x]. Since the array is finite, at some point arr[x] must be a value we've already seen, so we're in a loop and at the same time have found a duplicate. Since we know 0 isn't part of any loop, whatever look we're in must have been both entered and referred to by an element of the loop.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, thanks for the patience, but how do you handle the circle issue I mentioned. A[2] = 3, A[3] = 4 and A[4] =2, which makes faster and small into circle, which blocks them to find the real duplicate elements. Please feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa You are only giving a partial example. Any real example you give will be solved by the algorithm as long as the inputs are as stated: no zeroes, numbers chosen from 1 to n, and at most one repeated value. [1, 2, 3, 4, 2} satisfies your constraint and will be detected. So will [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5] so will any example you care to test.

Comment: @LinMa It doesn't matter if there are extra cycles, all that matters is that starting from position 0, you are definitely not in a cycle, and you will definitely end up in one if you keep going to the position indicated by your current spot in the array. The first element of that cycle will be pointed to by both an element in your path leading to the cycle, and an element in the cycle. Other cycles may exist, that isn't a problem.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, how your algorithm works for [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5]? I think your algorithm will stuck in cycle [3,4,2] without reaching the last 5? More details are appreciated and have a good weekend. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, "The first element of that cycle will be pointed to by both an element in your path leading to the cycle, and an element in the cycle.", this is true, just wondering how your algorithm works for  [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5]? In more general case, both pointers are stuck in a circle without reaching the remaining part of the array. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: $ irb
2.1.2 :001 > def find_dup(arr)
2.1.2 :002?>   len = arr.length
2.1.2 :003?>   slow = arr[0]
2.1.2 :004?>   fast = arr[arr[0]]
2.1.2 :005?>   while(slow != fast) do
2.1.2 :006 >       slow = arr[slow]
2.1.2 :007?>     fast = arr[arr[fast]]
2.1.2 :008?>     end
2.1.2 :009?>   fast = 0
2.1.2 :010?>   while(slow != fast) do
2.1.2 :011 >       slow = arr[slow]
2.1.2 :012?>     fast = arr[fast]
2.1.2 :013?>     end
2.1.2 :014?>   return slow
2.1.2 :015?>   end
 => :find_dup 
2.1.2 :016 > find_dup([1,5,3,4,2,5])
 => 5

Comment: The formatting there is terrible. It's Ruby code & output showing that this works for your sample array. I did a second run with logging so you can see every time the values change. Here goes: find_dup_loud([1,5,3,4,2,5])
`init: (1,5) 
loop 1: (5,5) 
fast reset to 0: (5,0) 
loop 2: (5, 1)  
loop 2: (5, 5)  
`

Comment: @LinMa It takes minutes to write your own version of this algorithm in some code and try it out. Why am I doing this for you? Do it yourself, add logging, and put in some test cases. Better yet, take your sample input and run through the algorithm by hand. It will be fast and you'll learn something.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, did debugging today and learned a lot from you. Want to confirm my understanding is correct, when there is a circle, there must be two elements in the array pointing to the entry point of circle, and faster/slower runner met at entry point of circle (in your algorithm), and it is why the index of array of begin circle is the duplicate elements? Correct? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Say that each time we advance fast & slow in the first loop is a 'move', and say that fast and slow intersect after k moves. At that time fast has moved 2k steps, and slow has moved k steps. We then reset fast to 0, and change its movement rate to 1 step per move. Notice that in another k steps slow will have moved a total of 2k steps from the beginning, and fast will have moved k steps, so they again intersect at the same place. Since we're checking fast and slow at each step, we find the first time they point to the same node, which will be your repeated value.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, understand the logics, just to confirm my understanding is correct, when there is a circle, there must be two elements in the array pointing to the entry point of circle, and faster/slower runner met at entry point of circle (in your algorithm), and it is why the index of array of begin circle is the duplicate elements, correct?

Comment: @LinMa Not exactly. I'll post a summary in a separate answer since this is hard to put in comments.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, I read your comments again above and did some exercise, I think my understanding, "when there is a circle, there must be two elements in the array pointing to the entry point of circle, and faster/slower runner met at entry point of circle (in your algorithm), and it is why the index of array of begin circle is the duplicate elements, correct? ", is exactly what you mean? If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me. :)

Answer (score 3):

The sum of integers from 1 to N = `(N * (N + 1)) / 2`. You can use this to find the duplicate -- sum the integers in the array, then subtract the above formula from the sum. That's the duplicate.

**Update**: The above solution is based on the (possibly invalid) assumption that the input array consists of the values from 1 to N plus a single duplicate.

Comment: Very smart, keithmo, but how do you prove there is duplicate?

Comment: "There is only one duplicate number in the array, but it could be repeated more than once." But the idea is great.

Comment: Oops, I missed the "...repeated more than once" part. My bad.

Comment: Hi keithmo, I think you are correct, there is only one duplicate number. The problem itself has issues.

Comment: I suppose the problem as described would allow, for example, N = 5 and the array = [1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2]. If so then my solution would fail badly.

Comment: @keithmo, I think your above scenario does not exists, since it is not N distinct numbers in N+1 slots. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use any additional space, using another hash table would be ruled out.

Now, coming to the approach of hashing on existing array, it can be acheived if we are allowed to modify the array in place.

> Algo:

1) Start with the first element.

2) Hash the  first element and apply a transformation to the value of hash.Let's say this transformation is making the value -ve.

3)Proceed to next element.Hash the element and before applying the transformation, check if a transformation has already been applied.

4) If yes, then element is a duplicate.

Code:

```
 for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if(arr[abs(arr[i])] > 0)
      arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
    else
      cout<< abs(arr[i]) <<endl;
  }
```

This transformation is required since if we are to use hashing approach,then,  there has to be a collision for hashing the same key.

I cant think of a way in which hashing can be used without any additional space and not modifying the array.

Comment: You cannot modify the existing array.

Comment: "I cant think of a way in which hashing can be used without any additional space and not modifying the array."...agreed.if hashing is to be used, then the array will have to be modified or else it's not possible.

Comment: @basav, ideas is smart and agree with n.m. and we should not modify the array. Thanks for the sharing.